Combining a RAM snapshot and an exe in Ghidra
I have two things: (1) A .exe file, and (2) a memory snapshot of a system running that .exe file at a moment in time.
Ghidra's auto analyzer very nicely figures out the .exe file and separates it into .text and .data sections. But the .exe file doesn't have the memory addresses or values that were used by the system at the moment the snapshot was taken.
Can I combine these two things in a useful way with Ghidra? I'd love it if the Ghidra file for the memory snapshot knew that the .exe was loaded in it - it's very helpful to have the right addresses and live values.
